# Read CSV file into HTML tables with Python

Tags: python, html, csv

I'm needing to input data from a CSV file and create a HTML table as the output.

I am currently working with:

```
with open('2016motogp.csv') as csvfile:
 reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
 for row in reader:
     print('<tr>')
     for fn in reader.fieldnames:
         print('<td>{}</td>'.format(row[fn]))
     print('</tr>')
```

The CSV file I want to read into the table is:
https://ufile.io/6joj6

When I run the function I get the error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-3a27549e50fe> in <module>()
----> 1 write_html_table("2016motogp")

<ipython-input-9-91d2a78b30ad> in write_html_table(filename)
     55     with open(filename + ".csv") as csvfile:
     56         reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
---> 57         for row in reader:
     58             print('<tr>')
     59             for fn in reader.fieldnames:

E:\Anaconda\lib\csv.py in __next__(self)
    109         if self.line_num == 0:
    110             # Used only for its side effect.
--> 111             self.fieldnames
    112         row = next(self.reader)
    113         self.line_num = self.reader.line_num

E:\Anaconda\lib\csv.py in fieldnames(self)
     96         if self._fieldnames is None:
     97             try:
---> 98                 self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
     99             except StopIteration:
    100                 pass

E:\Anaconda\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in decode(self, input, final)
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
     22     def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 23         return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
     24 
     25 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1037: character maps to <undefined>
```

If anybody provide some guidance or help out it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6):

**Use Python pandas DataFrame to_html method**

You could read the csv file into a Python pandas DataFrame. Then, use the DataFrame `to_html` feature to either create an HTML file or assign the result into a string and use it that way.  This converts the DataFrame into an HTML table.  See links to Python docs below.

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the csv file in
df = pd.read_csv('2016motogp.csv')

# Save to file
df.to_html('myTable.htm')

# Assign to string
htmTable = df.to_html()
```

[pandas read_csv doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

[pandas to_html doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html)

Comment: Thank you! Saved me. Pandas is so great!

Answer (score 3):

The error might be because the file in question might not be using CP1252 encoding. Assuming it's using `utf-8` encoding just add the encoding in `open` statement and it'll work. I have tested it.

```
import csv

table = ''
with open(csv_path, encoding="utf8") as csvFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    table = '<tr>{}</tr>'.format(''.join(['<td>{}</td>'.format(header) for header in reader.fieldnames]))
    for row in reader:
        table_row = '<tr>'
        for fn in reader.fieldnames:
            table_row += '<td>{}</td>'.format(row[fn])
        table_row += '</tr>'
        table += table_row
```

Comment: Certainly seems to have done something, this is the output now. http://imgur.com/0qGtzX2

Comment: You have to change your `delimter` as well.

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: Is there a reason it is not reading the top row with headers? It is beginning to look nicer now. http://imgur.com/OUW7o02

Comment: Thanks, I am still unsure of the unnecessary <tr></td> throughout and the \ufeff in the Year cell as well as the \xa0 before each riders name, how could this be addressed within the code? Here is the output https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FG5JLWTH57MF

Comment: It's because your csv has many blank fields. You can see [here](http://imgur.com/a/tg4sx)

Comment: Right, but It is displaying the end tag within each field of the output table? http://imgur.com/Ha7W8hJ

Comment: I think that's left to you as exercise ;-)

Comment: Thankyou for your help.